# Deploy only changed files on AWS Elastic Beanstalk website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have successfully deployed my website on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Now I want to change the code in one of my file.

If I do `eb deploy`, it will completely deploy a new version of my code which I don't want. I already have an updated DB on Elastic Beanstalk. If I deploy the whole code again, it will overwrite my DB file.

How can I deploy the changed file only successfully?

Comment: What kind of file do you have in your repo that would overwrite your entire db?

Comment: @littleforest I have my Django app deployed on it. So I'm using it's default Sqlite DB. It creates a separate file of DB and if I deploy again it will overwrite that copy of file.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer you're looking for, but I would highly recommend deleting this file from your code repository. Hopefully you're using a version control system like Git; if you want to keep the original file for historical purposes, I would create an entirely different repository and put it in there.

Why? Even if you did come up with a solution to only deploy changed files...would you really want to trust it? If there's any problem with the solution you came up with, you would entirely erase/overwrite your production database. Not good.

In addition, if you want to build a really robust system to entirely create your app from scratch in AWS, take a look at [Cloud Formation](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/). It takes some learning and work, but you can build a script -- and maintain it in version control -- that will scaffold your entire cloud infrastructure.